# Qt 5.3 full screen issue

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.3

I have a Qt application which runs on Ubuntu 12.04 Server with KDE plasma desktop. If I compile with Qt 4.8 full screen works as expected. With Qt 5.3, the window is getting bigger than the available resolution. If I set the resolution using the following code, it works.

```
QSize sz(QApplication::desktop()->size());
main_window->setFixedSize(sz.width() + 1, sz.height() + 1);
main_window->showFullScreen();
```

Is this the proper way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Qt is quite flexible in application sizing and provides you with a lots of informations (and options).

For what concerns `QApplication` you can use `QDesktopWidget`.

```
QDesktopWidget * screen = QApplication::desktop(); 
screen->availableGeometry();
```

As stated in the docs about `availableGeometry`:

> Returns the available geometry of the screen with index screen. What
>   is available will be **subrect of screenGeometry() based on what the
>   platform decides is available** (for example excludes the dock and menu
>   bar on Mac OS X, or the task bar on Windows). The default screen is
>   used if screen is -1.

Read the section "Use of the Primary Screen" in `QDesktopWidget` docs for details about the "default screen" and the general handling of multiple screens. Using these methods you will have *full control* over the way your application is laid out, even with multiple screens available.

For what concerns `QGuiApplication` you can use `QScreen`:

```
QScreen * screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
screen->availableGeometry();
```

Finally, in QML it is possible (and advisable) to use `Screen` object which provides `Screen.desktopAvailableWidth` and `Screen.desktopAvailableHeight` which ensure proper resizing with different versions of Android/iOS.